# Lost connection to device. ( Flutter )

Tags: flutter

every time I put a TextField in my Widget it always error Lost connection to device. I hope there is an answer for this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDizl.png)

Comment: Could you also share the code?

Comment: maybe I just give my case, so every time I put a TextField in my Widget or hot reload it always error Lost connection to device. I hope there is an answer for this

Comment: I am using a MacBook. The only time I faced this was when I wasn't closing the device simulator properly after running my code. (by properly I mean stopping the simulator process in Activity Monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect and reconnect the device you are using as an Emulator. This usually happens because you stay for too long without launching the test app.

Hope this helps you.